# SQL one id JOIN two names

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables. And I want to ask the color1 and color2 names.

```
id  color
0   white
1   black
2   blue
--------------------------     
carid   color1  color2
560     1   0
480     2   1
```

I tried with this, but it does'nt works well. While color2 has the color1-s name.

```
SELECT v.csapatnev,v.nev,v.navigator,vt.versenynev,a.autonev,g.geposztalynev,c.color
FROM verseny v 
JOIN versenytipus vt  ON v.versenyid=vt.id
JOIN autok a ON v.autoid=a.autoid
JOIN geposztalyok g ON a.geposztalyid=g.id
JOIN colors c ON c.id=v.color1
ORDER BY v.csapatnev
```

Comment: You have to JOIN to the color table twice. Add `JOIN colors AS c2 ON c2.id = v.color2` to your query

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201359/joining-the-same-table-twice-on-different-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do.

```
SELECT c1.color as color1, c2.color as color2
FROM CAR car
INNER JOIN COLOR c1 ON c1.id = car.color1
INNER JOIN COLOR c2 ON c2.id = car.color2
```