# Joining in same table with same column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables, that the one of them is information center table assumed table 1.

Table1 as (tank information)

```
-----------------------------------------
Prikey   TankName
-----------------------------------------
24       Tank1
25       Tank2
```

Table2 as (source)

```
-----------------------------------------
 ID         Tank Source ID   Opotional
-----------------------------------------
 1           25               Source
 2           24               test
            etc
```

Table3 as (Destination)

```
---------------------------------------------------
Tank Destination ID     Opotional      ID Source
---------------------------------------------------
25                      Destination    1 
24                      Destination    2
etc
```

I would like to get the "tank name" in twice and display the "Source" and "destination" with match ID of 'Tank'. So both of them having Tank ID that I use on one query. I have tried joined but is crashed. Is it possible?

Hope the result is :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Source (tank Name)   |  Destination (Tank Name)  | opotional (source) | Opotional (Destination)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Just join to the table twice and alias the table1 as STank and DTank or something.

Comment: Add the expected result too, not just the column names.

Comment: Please show the join you tried and what error you got.   It's certainly possible, so you must have done something wrong that we can debug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [joining the same table twice on different columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201359/joining-the-same-table-twice-on-different-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use aliases, Both on the tables that you join more than once (Table1) and on the fields that you return more than once (TankName, Optional).

Something like:

```
select Source.TankName as SourceTank, Destination.TankName as DestinationTank, 
       Table2.Optional as SourceOptional, Table3.Optional as DestionationOptional
from Table2
     inner join Table3 on Table3.ID = Table2.ID
     inner join Table1 as Source on Source.PriKey = Table2.TankID
     inner join Table1 as Destination on Destination.PriKey = Table3.TankID
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last `AS` in the last join be `ON`?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT [Table2].Opotional AS 'opotional (source)',
       [Table3].Opotional AS 'Opotional (Destination)',
       [Table1].TankName AS 'Source (tank Name)',
       t1.TankName AS 'Destination (Tank Name)'
FROM [Table2]
     INNER JOIN [Table3] ON Table3.[ID Source] = [Table2].[ID]
     INNER JOIN Table1 ON [Table2].[Tank Source ID] = [Table1].Prikey
     INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON Table3.[Tank Destination ID] = t1.Prikey;
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will help you to achieve the expected result..

```
select a.Tankname as [Source (tank Name)],
       a.Tankname as[Destination (Tank Name)],
       b.Optional as [Optional Source],
       c.Optional as [Optional Destination] 
from Table2 as b 
    join Table3 as c on b.ID = c.[ID Source] 
    join Table1 as a on c.[Tank Destination ID] = a.prikey
```

Comment: It lacks another join with Table1. You return the same value  Destination Tankname as both [Source (tank Name)] and [Destination (Tank Name)]

Comment: its going to be the same,why we need to join unnecessarily. For a double check we can join but that will make the query work slower.

Comment: He's asking how to Join Table1 more than once. In those sample rows they are the same, indeed, but I guess they don't "have to" always be the same Tank.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl1 as TABLE(
    Prikey  INT,
    TankName VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @tbl2 as TABLE(
   ID  INT,
   TankSourceID  INT,
   Opotional  VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @tbl3 as TABLE(
   TankDestinationID  INT,
   Opotional VARCHAR(50),
   IDSource  INT
)

INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(1,'Tank1')
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(2,'Tank2')
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(3,'Tank3')

INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES(1,1,'Source')
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES(2,3,'Test')

INSERT INTO @tbl3 VALUES(1,'Destination1',1)
INSERT INTO @tbl3 VALUES(2,'Destination2',2)


SELECT
    T1.TankName AS 'Source',
    T1_2.TankName AS 'Destination',
    T2.Opotional AS 'SourceOpotional',
    T3.Opotional AS 'DestinationOpotional'
FROM @tbl2 T2
LEFT JOIN @tbl1 T1 ON T1.Prikey=T2.TankSourceID
LEFT JOIN @tbl3 T3 ON T2.TankSourceID=T3.TankDestinationID
LEFT JOIN @tbl1 T1_2 ON T3.TankDestinationID=T1_2.Prikey
```