# What is this pattern in SQL

Tags: sql-server

have a table that contains this format:

HistoryDataTbl:

```
Id, LookupId, PreviousValueReferenceId, CurrentValueReferenceId, UpdatedDate
```

ReferenceDataTbl:

```
Id, Value
```

ReferenceData Sample:

```
Id Value

1, ValueA
2, ValueB
3, ValueC
4, ValueD
```

HistoryDataTbl Sample:

```
Id PreviousValueId CurrentValueId UpdatedDate

1       1               1         '2017-01-10 14:38:51.110'
2       3               2         '2017-02-10 14:38:51.110'
3       1               4         '2017-03-10 14:38:51.110'
4       2               3         '2017-04-10 14:38:51.110'
```

HistoryDataTbl has multiple rows pointing to value in the ReferenceDataTbl.
How do I show on one line each the PreviousValue and CurrentValue while joining to the ReferenceDataTbl?

```
select UpdatedDate
,(select top 1 [value] from ReferenceData where id = 
hd.PreviousValueReferenceId) as PreviousValue
,(select top 1 [value] from ReferenceData where id = 
hd.CurrentValueReferenceId) as CurrentValue
FROM HistoryData hdt
order by UpdatedDate
```

Pretty sure the pattern I'm trying to use is wrong since I had to do top 1 because of "Subquery returned more than 1 value". What pattern needs to be applied here?

Updated the post since after trying out the posted solution it is now returning 4 rows while there are only 2 HistoryDataTbl entris. That needs to return only 2 entries.

The linked thread as duplicate did not help me as much as this thread did so don't want to accept that.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Two joins, first join `on hdt.PreviousValueReferenceId = r.Id` and second join `on hdt.CurrentValueReferenceId = r.Id`

Comment: Add sample data and expected result...

Comment: @AaronLS Thank you so much! Can't believe it was that easy. Don't see a way to accept your answer, so let me know how to do that.

Comment: If there's more than 1 row for both `PreviousValueReferenceId` and `CurrentValueReferenceId` you will get a result that has 1 row for every PreviousValueReferenceId for every CurrentValueReferenceId, and that's not usually what people actually want, because 10 rows in each becomes 100 rows.

Comment: @JamesZ thank you, you are right, HistoryData has 4 entries for 1 reference and now its returning 16 records. Each unique combination is returned 4 times total, that should be displayed only 1 time. What do I need to do now?

Comment: Guessing that you want them in some kind of time related order, you could add row_number() for the data (so you have rows numbed 1...x) and then you could use that to full outer join the both to each other... so you might want to add a more complex example (with some data) to your question.

Comment: @JamesZ added more data to the post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [joining the same table twice on different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201359/joining-the-same-table-twice-on-different-columns)

Comment: @TabAlleman This isn't a duplicate of that - he needs `CROSS APPLY` because he wants only one row returned for each parents record - even though it joins to two child records.

Comment: Never ever use correlated sub-queries, they are performance killers and a truly bad technique.

Comment: @StanShaw, the answer in the duplicate question would only return one row for each "parent" row (row in `HistoryDatatbl`).   What makes you think that it wouldn't?   Or am I misunderstanding what you consider a "parent" row to be?   If OP posted some desired results, maybe it would be clear.

Comment: @TabAlleman My apologies - I didn't see the `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy - you just need to join to the reference table twice - once for each value:

```
SELECT  H.ID, 
        H.LookupID, 
        Prev.Value AS [Previous Value], 
        Curr.Value AS [Current Value], 
        H.UpdatedDate
FROM HistoryDataTbl H
JOIN ReferenceDataTable Prev
    ON H.PreviousValueReferenceID = Prev.ID
JOIN ReferenceDataTbl Curr
    ON H.CurrentValueReferenceID = Curr.ID
```

EDIT:

You said you want only one row - you can achieve that with `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT  H.ID, 
        H.LookupID, 
        Prev.Value AS [Previous Value], 
        Curr.Value AS [Current Value], 
        H.UpdatedDate
FROM HistoryDataTbl H
CROSS APPLY
    (   
        SELECT [Value] 
        FROM ReferenceDataTable R
        WHERE R.ID = H.PreviousValueReferenceID
    ) Prev
CROSS APPLY
    (   
        SELECT [Value]
        FROM ReferenceDataTable R2
        WHERE R2.ID = H.CurrentValueReferenceID
    ) Curr
```

Comment: Tried this and its giving 4 rows when there are only 2 entries. Needs to show only 2 entries per event. Updated my post.

Comment: @SqlQueryLink I edited my answer with a `CROSS APPLY` - that should be what you need.

Comment: Thank you, that did it! Now will have to read up on cross apply.

Comment: @SqlQueryLink Glad to help - `CROSS APPLY` is great and better than subqueries in many ways.  Enjoy!