# Query twice on same table for different columns

Tags: sql-server, nested, self-join

SQL Server 2008:

I have a hierarchy of employees and managers (all with employee ID numbers). The Boss is Alice and Bill's manager... Alice is Claudia and Tim's mgr... Bill is Fred's mgr.

```
              The Boss (100)
                    |
           +------------------+
           |                  |
      Alice(101)           Bill(102)
           |                  |
     +-----------+            |
Claudia(103)  Tim(104)     Fred(105)
```

Table wise, there are two tables an empl master table (employee_peeps) and then a table of manager to employee relationships (manager_codes). The tables look like this:

```
employee_peeps:            manager_codes
badge_ID  emplName         badge_ID  manager_ID
--------  --------         --------  ----------
100       The Boss         100       0
101       Alice            101       100
102       Bill             102       100
103       Claudia          103       101
104       Tim              104       101
105       Fred             105       102
```

I'm trying to query the main table twice - once for the employee names and then again for the manager's names in the same row. I've tried to follow the logic in [joining the same table twice on different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201359/joining-the-same-table-twice-on-different-columns) but can't seem to make anything happen. What I'm looking for is this:

```
Desired result:

badge_ID  Employee  Manager
--------  --------  -------
100       The Boss  {null}
101       Alice     The Boss
102       Bill      The Boss
103       Claudia   Alice
104       Tim       Alice
105       Fred      Bill
```

We have 300 employees... Theoretically only the President of the company does not have a boss. Is there a way in one SQL statement to query the employee names, then hit the main table again to get the manager's name on the same resulting row?

Here's some consumable code to make the tables for this example:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_peeps
    ([badge_ID] int, [emplName] varchar(15))
;
INSERT INTO employee_peeps
    ([badge_ID], [emplName])
VALUES
    (100, 'The Boss'),
    (101, 'Alice'),
    (102, 'Bill'),
    (103, 'Claudia'),
    (104, 'Tim'),
    (105, 'Fred')
;
CREATE TABLE manager_codes
    ([badge_ID] int, [manager_ID] int)
INSERT INTO manager_codes
    ([badge_ID], [manager_ID])
VALUES
    (100,0),
    (101,100),
    (102,100),
    (103,101),
    (104,101),
    (105,102)
;
```

Thanks,
John

Comment: So, based on the linked question, what did you write? Why does it not work for you?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I tried this: `select a.badge_ID, a.emplName, b.manager_ID
  from employee_peeps a 
  LEFT JOIN manager_codes b on b.manager_ID = a.badge_ID
  LEFT JOIN employee_peeps a on b.badge_ID = a.badge_ID` which errors with 'a' specified multiple times

Comment: how do I carriage-return and format code in replies?

Comment: Just for future reference, don't. *[edit]* your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this was answered already (thank you @cetin basoz), but I went back to [joining the same table twice on different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201359/joining-the-same-table-twice-on-different-columns) to try and figure that out again. I downloaded FlySpeed and tried building the query visually by dragging the employee_peeps table into the builder twice (as employee_peeps1 for the second instance). The builder did build the statement in the same format of that other post with two inner joins - and it works. Thanks again for everyone's help.

```
SELECT
  employee_peeps.badge_ID,
  employee_peeps.emplName,
  manager_codes.manager_ID,
  employee_peeps1.emplName AS emplName1
FROM
  employee_peeps
  INNER JOIN manager_codes ON manager_codes.badge_ID =
    employee_peeps.badge_ID
  INNER JOIN employee_peeps employee_peeps1 ON
    employee_peeps1.badge_ID = manager_codes.manager_ID
```

Comment: And you think this is better and work under all circumstances? There might be N ways to do the same thing and that doesn't mean, writing in another style nullifies the other.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
e.badge_id, e.emplName, t.manager_id, t.managerName
from employee_peeps e
outer apply (select m.manager_id,
             e2.emplName 
             from manager_codes m
             inner join employee_peeps e2 on m.manager_id = e2.badge_id
             where m.badge_id = e.badge_id
             ) t (manager_id, managerName);
```