# MYSQL - JOIN TABLE multiple times Getting single Value based on multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to access records from **ssku** data
[image]

and forecast
[image]

I need a query to get below output
[image]

Requirement Get **All data** from SSKU table and join forecast table **6** times(sep,oct,nov,dec,jan,feb) to get 'qty' of that particular 'month_year' and salesID max 'Version' (latest version)

Sorry i am very bad at explanation. I can improvise the question based on your doubts if any.

I am very bad at mysql. I know only simple SQL. Complex nesting is not known please help.

**Table** **structure** as below:

```
`**ahlaan_ssku`** 
CREATE TABLE `ahlaan_ssku` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `PlantID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `FormatID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SSKU` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Description` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
 `MarketID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ReplPolicy` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SalesManagerID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ActiveStatus` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `Modified_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Modified_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=411 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


**`ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales`** 
CREATE TABLE `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `SSKUID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Month_Year` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `Qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `StatusID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Version` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `Modified_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Modified_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Query I Tried

```
SELECT 
ssku.`id` as SSKUID, 
ssku.`SSKU`, 
ssku.`Description`,
salesForecastSep.Qty as Sep_2021_qty, salesForecastSep.Version as Sep2021_Version,
salesForecastOct.Qty as Oct_2021_qty, salesForecastOct.Version as Oct2021_Version,
salesForecastNov.Qty as Nov_2021_qty, salesForecastNov.Version as Nov2021_Version,
salesForecastDec.Qty as Dec_2021_qty, salesForecastDec.Version as Dec2021_Version,
salesForecastJan.Qty as Jan_2021_qty, salesForecastJan.Version as Jan2021_Version,
salesForecastFeb.Qty as Feb_2021_qty, salesForecastFeb.Version as Feb2021_Version
FROM `ahlaan_ssku` ssku 
   LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT * FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` WHERE Month_Year = '2021-09-01'  AND id IN (
            SELECT max(id) FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` GROUP BY Month_Year 
        ) 
    ) AS salesForecastSep ON ssku.id = salesForecastSep.SSKUID AND salesForecastSep.Month_Year = '2021-09-01' 
   LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT * FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` WHERE Month_Year = '2021-10-01'  AND id IN (
            SELECT max(id) FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` GROUP BY Month_Year 
        ) 
   ) AS salesForecastOct ON ssku.id = salesForecastOct.SSKUID AND salesForecastOct.Month_Year = '2021-10-01' 
   LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT * FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` WHERE Month_Year = '2021-11-01'  AND id IN (
            SELECT max(id) FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` GROUP BY Month_Year 
        ) 
   ) AS salesForecastNov ON ssku.id = salesForecastNov.SSKUID AND salesForecastNov.Month_Year = '2021-11-01' 
   LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT * FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` WHERE Month_Year = '2021-12-01'  AND id IN (
            SELECT max(id) FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` GROUP BY Month_Year 
        ) 
   ) AS salesForecastDec ON ssku.id = salesForecastDec.SSKUID AND salesForecastDec.Month_Year = '2021-12-01' 
   LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT * FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` WHERE Month_Year = '2022-01-01'  AND id IN (
            SELECT max(id) FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` GROUP BY Month_Year 
        ) 
   ) AS salesForecastJan ON ssku.id = salesForecastJan.SSKUID AND salesForecastJan.Month_Year = '2022-01-01' 
   LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT * FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` WHERE Month_Year = '2022-02-01'  AND id IN (
            SELECT max(id) FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` GROUP BY Month_Year 
        ) 
    ) AS salesForecastFeb ON ssku.id = salesForecastFeb.SSKUID AND salesForecastFeb.Month_Year = '2022-02-01'  WHERE ssku.ActiveStatus = '1' AND `SalesManagerID` = 302
```

It gives me values for 6 months but only for one SSKU other SSKU values are shown null

Comment: please provide table structure with few data based on requirement and expected output. Not image...

Comment: i have created table using phpMyAdmin is there a way to extract the query or 'desc tablename' data is enough

Comment: Query `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;`. Or backup the table into .SQL file.

Comment: @akina thank you i will update with structure in a minute

Comment: do u need six month data or six month is fixed here.

Comment: @RahulBiswas : six month fixed. Here the Report must display the  last updated forecast of six months for each ssku

Comment: @VivanMenezes consider quantity for latest version of every SSKUID

Comment: @RahulBiswas I shared the query I use

Comment: @brian-hooper Thanks user answer in post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201359/joining-the-same-table-twice-on-different-columns/3201371 solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I have removed all left joins and added below code inside select

```
  (SELECT Qty FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` WHERE SSKUID = ssku.`id` AND Month_Year = '2021-10-01' ORDER BY Version DESC LIMIT 1) as Oct_2021, 
(SELECT Qty FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` WHERE SSKUID = ssku.`id` AND Month_Year = '2021-11-01' ORDER BY Version DESC LIMIT 1) as Nov_2021, 
(SELECT Qty FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` WHERE SSKUID = ssku.`id` AND Month_Year = '2021-12-01' ORDER BY Version DESC LIMIT 1) as Dec_2021, 
(SELECT Qty FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` WHERE SSKUID = ssku.`id` AND Month_Year = '2022-01-01' ORDER BY Version DESC LIMIT 1) as Jan_2022, 
(SELECT Qty FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` WHERE SSKUID = ssku.`id` AND Month_Year = '2022-02-01' ORDER BY Version DESC LIMIT 1) as Feb_2022, 
(SELECT Qty FROM `ahlaan_forecast_monthly_sales` WHERE SSKUID = ssku.`id` AND Month_Year = '2022-03-01' ORDER BY Version DESC LIMIT 1) as Mar_2022
```

This gave me my desired output